# Python Pandas with functions and column equal values

Tags: python, pandas, global-variables, dataframe

I am trying to create a function that takes an already formatted 
json.loads().

```
def data_fp(fp):
    for line in fp:
    try:
         data=json.loads(line)
         json_data.append(data)
    except:
        continue
```

I take the json_data and am trying to clean it. I created a blank dataframe and made a function.

```
df=pd.DataFrame()

def data_clean(liste):
    df['col1'] = map(lambda datas: datas['col1'] if 'col1' in datas else 'NA', liste)
    df['col2'] = map(lambda datas: datas['col2'] if 'col2' in datas else 'NA', liste)
    df=df[df['col2']=='foo']
```

The problem comes from the last line. When I include it in the function, I get an error

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before
>   assignment

But when I run the function without the last line in it, I get no errors, and I can run the == line in the console and get the desired result.

Why does it not work in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variable assigned in a function is local to that function, unless it is specifically declared global. So without assignment you access the global variable and everything goes fine, with assignment you access a non-declared local variable hence an error.

Look here: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-you-set-a-global-variable-in-a-function.htm